# Why doesnt mysql code return the column 'Sub Category'

Tags: mysql

I imported a table supermarket from Excel with a column named Sub Category. Now  I am querying  a SQL CODE to return the column Sub category but I get error 1054, 'sub'  unknown column in the field list

```
SELECT Sub Category FROM supermarket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column name has whitespace inside it,you can use **`** to wrap it

```
SELECT `Sub Category` FROM supermarket
```